# [Rails]Routes doesn't work with some nouns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

(I'm french)
I've a problem with my Rails (3.2.11) application. When i set my routes with some nouns, it doesn't work !
I explain:

```
Way::Application.routes.draw do
  scope(:path_names => { :new => "nouveau", :edit => "edition" }) do

    scope "/admin" do
      resources :news, except: [:show, :index], path: '/articles'
      resources :users, except: [:show]
      resources :pages, except: [:show]
      resources :events, except: [:show, :index]
      resources :projects, except: [:show,:index], path: '/projets'
      resources :galleries, except: [:index, :show] do 
        resources :paintings, except: [:index, :show]
      end
   end
end
```

end

The resources :projects doesn't work when i set it to "/projets".
What doesn't work is: when i want to create a new project in my form, i click on submit, it simply redirect me to "/projets", without doing something !
But when i set the route to "/poneys" for example, it works ! I really don't understand.
Thanks for your help.

https://github.com/khcr/way

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  def new
   @project = Project.new
   render layout: 'admin'
  end

  def create 
    @project = Project.new(params[:project])
    if @project.save
      flash[:success] = "Projet créé"
      redirect_to project_path(@project)
    else
      render 'new', layout: 'admin'
    end
  end
end
```